# the sum of the reciprocals of the lengths of the interior angle bisectors of a triangle and the sum of the reciprocals of the lengths of the sides

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

I have been struggling with this problem:

> Prove that the sum of the reciprocals of the lengths of the interior angle
>   bisectors of a triangle is greater than the sum of the reciprocals of the
>   lengths of the sides of the triangle

I have tried different approaches to solve it here are some of them :

**-The relation between the measures of angles in a triangle and the lengths of sides**

**-Trying triangle inequality on different triangles**

**-Using some formulas and inequalities involving angle bisectors and sides**

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve it.

I don't want the full solution I just need some hints and suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $l_a$ be the length of the angle bisector of the angle $\hat A$ in the given triangle. Using usual notations,
$$
l_a^2 =\frac 1{(b+c)^2}\; 4bc\; p(p-a)\  .
$$
(Here, $a,b,c$ are the sides of $\Delta ABC$, and $p=\frac 12(a+b+c)$ is the half-perimeter.)
Then we have 
$$   
\tag{$*$}
\frac 2{l_a}=\frac {b+c}{\sqrt{bc\; p(p-a)}}
\color{red}{\ge}
\frac{b+c}{bc}=\frac 1b+\frac 1c\ .
$$
Indeed, the red inequality is successively equivalent to...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{bc\; p(p-a)} &\le bc\ ,\\
p(p-a) &\le bc\ ,\\
((b+c)+a)((b+c)-a) &\le 4bc\ ,\\
(b+c)^2-a^2 &\le 4bc\ ,\\
(b+c)^2-4bc -a^2&\le 0\ ,\\
(b-c)^2 -a^2&\le 0\ ,\\
(b-c-a)(b-c+a)&\le 0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And the last inequality is true. Now use cyclic cousins of $(*)$, and add all three inequalities.

Comment: Your relation $(\star)$ is key, but there's a way to get to it without having to know the length of the angle bisector. (Without giving too much away to OP ...) Consider triangle areas (plural) computable using elements neighboring vertex $A$.

Comment: Note that the OP wants only a *hint*. The length of the angle bisector is usually computed using Stewart' Theorem, and it is not a big problem. The solution involving the equality of the sum of the two areas separated by the angle bisector, $$bl_a\sin\frac A2 + cl_a\sin\frac A2= bc\sin A=2bc\sin \frac A2\cos\frac A2\ $$ and division with $bcl_a$ is an other way to go. I found it simpler as typed. Now i also got some -1... To be well understood, the idea to write down and check $(*)$ came with the formula. It is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Blue: Just omit everything after "Indeed...", since there are too many lines written, only the last inequality in the row may be sufficient for experienced solvers, and consider $(*)$ as a hint.

Comment: Somebody put some -1 on a valid solution, may i please know the reason?!

Comment: "Note that the OP wants only a *hint*." Absolutely. That's why I vaguely described the area-based approach instead of giving the explicit relation. Be that as it may ... I wasn't suggesting there was anything *wrong* with your solution. (I didn't downvote.) I just wanted to point out an alternative. I do *happen* to find the alternative simpler (reducing the argument to a line or two, without an off-the-page invocation of Stewart), but, as you mention, it is a matter of taste. And I wrote a comment rather than an answer because the approach to $(\star)$ is less important than $(\star)$ itself.

Comment: @Blue Your way to see is a valid, valuable point, and would deserve at any rate a parallel answer. In my comments i was slightly irritated by the downvote, an anonymous can not appreciate the effort to type formulas and sentences in the right order, it often happens to me last time, it is almost a pattern... I will wait some more days, if the downvote survives, i will delete the answer.